# Why one is allowed to downvote an answer and accept it simultaneously?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

It really does not make sense to me that *why one is allowed to downvote an answer and accept it simultaneously?*

How can one show disagreement and agreement simultaneously? Non-sense it is!

Comment: How can one downvote a question and post an answer? How can one vote to close and post an answer? How can one tell a man she loves him, but sleep around with other guys? The world is an oxymoron. Get with the program...

Comment: Acceptance may not mean agreement.  It may mean "this answer helped me".  Perhaps even a wrong answer could help the OP.

Comment: @AsafKaragila downvoting along with posting an answer, flagging and posting an answer simultaneously, makes sense. How it doesn't?

Comment: @GEdgar how can a wrong answer help OP?

Comment: How do you manage to carry out those two actions simultaneously? You log in with two devices, and you downvote with your left hand while accepting with your right hand? Seems like a lot of trouble; I can't imagine why anyone would bother.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree it should most of the time (though one could envision scenarios) make little sense to accept an answer and to down-vote. However, not everything that makes little sense needs to (or even should) be prevented by the software.

If you think it is a non-sense to do it, just don't do it.

Comment: I kind of hope this is downvoted and accepted.

Comment: That's not nice calling for downvotes here. "You should really consider calming down a little bit." ;D

Comment: :) I swear, I didn't vote it down!

Comment: @SufyanNaeem Not sure about that, but I am certain you didn't upvote it. ;-)

Comment: Correct! I didn't upvote it but didn't downvote it at least! It must be you who downvoted. Isn't so? ;)

Comment: @quid: Seeing this at +0/-1 and accepted made my day! (Very calm now.) Drat, someone upvoted it. Oh well.

Comment: @ArthurFischer Meta posts can not be considered for my question. Here an upvote merely means agreement and downvote merely means disagreement! Question has some thing to do with Math.SE, Phy.SE and some more where upvote means good, appreciation or a kind of help and downvote means that there must be be a mistake in question or answer whatsoever..

Comment: @ArthurFischer I am always glad to help entertain my fellow users. Conversely, I was quite amused by your "thanks," close manouver.  So I guess we are even :-)

Comment: On meta sites, it may be reasonable to accept and downvote. For example, if it's the authoritative answer (SE employee declining feature request) that you disagree with.

Comment: @2mkgz this is a good point. In fact, my original version said "on main" at the start, as I meant to mention this but then I did not so I deleted that too.